# Python Best Practice. Call commandline python file from another python file

Tags: python

I retrieved a python project from some git repo. To run this project, there is a file that must be launched by command line with the correct arguments. Here is an example :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description')
parser.add_argument('arg1')
parser.add_argument('arg2')

# %%
def _main(args):
    # Execute the code using args


if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main(parser.parse_args())
```

I want to use this code in my own project, and so, call the main function from another python file, using a set of predefined arguments.

I have found different ways of doing so, but I don't know what is the good way to do it.

- Calling the file using the os package, but seems like a bad practice to me.
- Refactoring the file so that the main function take the wanted parameters (and getting rid of args object), but it means that command line call would not work anymore.
- Other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import `otherprogram` into your own program.

Call `otherprogram._main()` from the appropriate point in your own code, passing it an `argparse.Namespace` instance.

You can build that using your own `argparse` calls if you need to, or just construct the values some other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually call the main method as long as you make sure args contain the object with the correct attributes. Consider this

```py
import argparse

def _main(args):
    print(args.arg1)

_main(argparse.Namespace(arg1='test1', arg2='test2'))
```

In another file you can do this:

```py
from some_git_repo import _main
from argparse import Namespace

_main(Namespace(arg1='test1', arg2='test2'))
```